# System.Windows.Forms.Screen Bouds reporting different in Powershell ISE to Powershell Console

Tags: powershell

I have the code below that successfully blanks out the second / 3rd monitor when running in Powershell ISE but when I run it in the console or from a scheduled task it only blanks out half of the screen. After doing some investigation I noticed screen bounds were reporting differently in the console thus causing the issue.  Any ideas on how to resole this so that when running in the console the additional monitor are blanked out correctly ?

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$screens = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::Allscreens | Where-Object Primary -eq $false
$synchash.screens = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
foreach($screen in $screens){ 
    $synchash.screens.Add($screen.devicename.replace('\','').replace('.','')[-1])
}
foreach ($screen in $screens){
    $synchash."$($screen.devicename.replace('\','').replace('.',''))" = $screen
    $newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
    $newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    $newRunspace.Open()
    $newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)
    $PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        function LoadXaml ($filename){
            $XamlLoader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument)
            $XamlLoader.Load($filename)
            return $XamlLoader
        }
        $screenNum = $synchash.screens[0]
        $display = "Display" + $screenNum
        $synchash.screens.RemoveAt(0)


        $XamlMainWindow = LoadXaml("\blankScreen.xaml")
        $reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XamlMainWindow)
        $syncHash."Window$screenNum" = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)



        [xml]$XAML = $XamlMainWindow
        $XamlMainWindow.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
        #Find all of the form types and add them as members to the synchash
        $syncHash.Add($("" + $_.Name + $screenNum),$syncHash."Window$screenNum".FindName($_.Name) )
        }

        $syncHash."Window$screenNum".Top = $synchash.$display.bounds.Top;
        $syncHash."Window$screenNum".Left = $synchash.$display.bounds.Left;
        $syncHash."Window$screenNum".Width = $synchash.$display.bounds.Width;
        $syncHash."Window$screenNum".Height = $synchash.$display.bounds.Height;
        $synchash."Window$screenNum".Show()

        $synchash."error$screenNum" = $error
    })
    $PowerShell.Runspace = $newRunspace
    [void]$Jobs.Add((
        [pscustomobject]@{
            PowerShell = $PowerShell
            Runspace = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
        }
    ))
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the various properties and what differences there are between console and ISE?  This is part of the reason people don't use the ISE as a test environment since it's not consistent.

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again. There is nothing wrong with writing code in the ISE (even though Visual Studio Code is better) but never test code there.

Comment: I have tried on several machines and on all the machine I get the same result.  i.e. it works fine when running from the ISE but not from the console.  In all circumstances it is a default setup of Powershell in Windows 10.  I have also tried on a Windows 7 box and get the same issue  > $psversiontable.psversion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117

Comment: Have you tried getting the screen size from WMI instead.

Comment: I just tried [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::Allscreens  in both the console and the ISE.  The ise returns both of my monitors but the console only the primary monitor is returned.  The reason for using [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::Allscreens is so I can display a blank form on all non primary monitors and I dont think I can do this with WMI

Comment: You can't ***display*** a blank screen but you should be able to get the size of each screen.

Comment: Also, I just did [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::Allscreens and got my two monitors in a console session. I would say that you are having some sort of envirnmental specific issue.

Comment: The reason I want to display a blank form on all non primary monitors is I have a form that displays on the primary monitor (Full screen) and I want the users to interact with that, therefore blanking out all secondary monitors is required to force them to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.